# How to create GUI for Glassfish custom Java application?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, glassfish

I would like to create a custom GUI for the application that I wrote for Glasshfish. Since the program is run by Glassfish, a Main method wouldn't help in this case. I also tried displaying a JFrame at the init() method but nothing shows up. Has anyone tried this?

Answer (score 2):

1. create `SplashScreen`
2. start `Glasshfish`
3. create `GUI`
4. add required vakue to the GUI
5. if Glasshfish started and GUI created, then hide SplashScreen and show GUI